# Как представить двустороннее отношение взаимной дружбы в БД?

Tags: sql, база-данных, структуры-данных, модель-данных, многие-ко-многим

Я хочу реализовать **взаимные дружеские связи** между пользователями в базе данных.
Но как лучше всего представить такую связь в БД? Возможно ли это?

Для примера я возьму образец из Prisma.
**Отношение подписчика** [реализовано там так](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations), хотя оно не гарантирует взаимности:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "User" (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('"User_id_seq"'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
);
CREATE TABLE "_UserFollows" (
    "A" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "User"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    "B" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "User"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

```
model User {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String?
  followedBy Follows[] @relation("following")
  following  Follows[] @relation("follower")
}

model Follows {
  follower    User @relation("follower", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followerId  Int
  following   User @relation("following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  followingId Int

  @@id([followerId, followingId])
}
```

Кроме того, каким образом я могу сделать так,
чтобы при удалении связи с одной стороны, удалялась и связь с другой стороны?

Как я могу обеспечить целостность данных и атомарность изменений?

Comment: триггерами видимо

Comment: @teran То есть самый адекватный способ реализации этого отношения, это всё-таки в приложении реализовывать спаренные транзакции добавления / удаления двух связей одновременно, да?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76016422/whats-the-best-way-to-model-a-mutual-friendship-relationship-in-a-db

Comment: непонятно, зачем дружбу делать атомарной операцией. скажем А поклонник Б, а Б поклонник А. у них дружба. А перестал быть поклонником Б. дружбы не стало, но Б может оставаться поклонником А.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Если всё упростить с точки зрения реализации в БД, то да, это будет проще. Но всё-таки двунаправленные связи такого рода не так уж и редки на практике. В конце концов довольно просто ведь представить какие-то привилегии, обусловленные взаимностью.